# Get all terms inside a specific taxonomy in a multisite

Tags: multisite, taxonomy

I have a father blog / main blog inside a multisite that has a specific taxonomy with 20+ terms inside it. i just need a list of all the terms inside that taxonomy...

i dont mind quering using WPDB but just dont know to how to write it correctly  or in any other way i tried use: "**switch_to_blog**" but that doesnt work when quering terms

**Any suggestion?**
i tried the:  Multisite Global Terms plugin (doesnt work)...

**EDIT (response to question in comment)**
this is an example of switch_to_blog i tried:

```
function multisite_profession_select(){

        switch_to_blog(1);

        $taxonomies = array('rsitecat');
        $args       = array('hide_empty' => false);
        $terms      = get_terms($taxonomies, $args );

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($terms);
        echo '</pre>';

        restore_current_blog();

    }
```

**The reponse i get:**

```
WP_ERROR OBJECT
(
    [ERRORS] => ARRAY
        (
            [INVALID_TAXONOMY] => ARRAY
                (
                    [0] => INVALID TAXONOMY
                )

        )

    [ERROR_DATA] => ARRAY
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: What exactly had you tried with `switch_to_blog()`? In general case it should work...

Comment: i have edited my question to include a more readbale reponse.

Comment: Hmhm... You sure the name is correct, no typo in it or anything? What if you try with native taxonomy like category?

Comment: will try now Rarst (and thanks for trying to help)

Comment: (a while later - too much work) - works for category - doesnt for taxonomy... the tax name is the correct one. also tried other taxonomies. is this an option in wordpress? if so.. is there a way to go around the issuse?

Comment: Are you sure the taxonomy exists in that context? At that site and the time you are trying to run the code?

Comment: Yep. It exists and have terms inside it. would you like to have a temp login (how to send it)?  p.s: also tried "Multisite Global Terms" plugin... no go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No way to do that in a "word press" way...

```
function multisite_profession_select(){
    switch_to_blog(1);
    $taxonomies = array('rsitecat');

    $check_later = array();
    global $wp_taxonomies;
    foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy){
        if (isset($wp_taxonomies[$taxonomy])){
            $check_later[$taxonomy] = false;
        } else {
            $wp_taxonomies[$taxonomy] = true;
            $check_later[$taxonomy] = true;
        }
    }

    $args       = array('hide_empty' => false);
    $terms      = get_terms($taxonomies, $args );

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($terms);
    echo '</pre>';


    if (isset($check_later))
        foreach($check_later as $taxonomy => $unset)
            if ($unset == true)
                unset($wp_taxonomies[$taxonomy]);

    restore_current_blog();
}
```

WP will check if Taxonomy exists, but on multisite blog, its only switching $table_prefix but not actually switching to blog. In this fixed code - it should trick WP to think that taxonomy registred and retrive a term from a mu blog tables. after request - you killing fake taxonomy ghosts.

P/S/

I didn't test code.

Comment: man - that was fast, and... thanks for the extra information.

Comment: Beautifully done. Thank you!

Comment: Hi there but this code is not working when I am trying to get child terms using parent  argument

Answer (score 2):

If you have problems getting data from another blog, polyfixes like temporarily registering taxonomies, etc. are a real pita in the long term.

You can't really rely on that workarounds, since such workarounds mimic internal wp infrastructure that changes over time.

**Best practice imho** would be to register a rest api endpoint (https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) or an xmlrpc endpoint (https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Extending). The endpoint fetches all data you need and returns it as json. So you always have a clean local context of the blog queried and don't have to struggle with missing infrastructure.

Would be something like this in the source blog:

```
add_action( 
    'rest_api_init', 
    function () {
        register_rest_route('your-namespace', '/get-terms/(?P<taxonomy>\d+)', array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => function($data) {
                $taxonomy_slug = $data['taxonomy'];
                return get_terms($taxonomy_slug, array('hide_empty' => false));
            }
        ));
    }
);
```

And something like that in the requesting blog:

```
$api_request = 'http://the.domain.of.your.blog/wp-json/your-namespace/get-terms/slug-of-taxonomy';
$api_response = wp_remote_get($api_request);
$taxonomy_terms = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($api_response), true);
```

Hope, that helps and best regards from Salzburg!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Already marked a correct answer but you got an UpVote - Best Regards from israel ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to solve, with [**wpdb**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/) object:

```
function multisite_profession_select(){
    global $wpdb;

    switch_to_blog(1);

    $taxonomies = array('rsitecat');
    $taxonomies = implode( "','", $taxonomies );

    $terms = $wpdb->get_results( "
        SELECT t.*
        FROM
            {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy AS tt
        INNER JOIN
            {$wpdb->prefix}terms AS t
            ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
        WHERE
            tt.taxonomy IN ( '{$taxonomies}' )
    " );

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($terms);
    echo '</pre>';

    restore_current_blog();
}
```