# get_term_by works but get_terms doesn't?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, multisite, terms, switch-to-blog

I currently have a Multisite with 2 sites.

From the secondary site `get_term_by()` works to retrieve terms from the primary site, but `get_terms()` does not.

I'm using `switch_to_blog(1);` but I get `object(WP_Error)#1316 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["invalid_taxonomy"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "Invalid taxonomy" } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }` when I run `get_terms()`

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I think this link will help you. It has similar question. Please check answer: [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189035/get-all-terms-inside-a-specific-taxonomy-in-a-multisite](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189035/get-all-terms-inside-a-specific-taxonomy-in-a-multisite)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer, which seems to be an issue with WordPress.

Using get_terms() to get terms from another site WORKS, BUT A TAXONOMY BY THE SAME NAME MUST BE PRESENT ON THE SUBSITE YOU'RE WORKING FROM.

Below is my code (working):

```
switch_to_blog(1);

$taxonomy = array( 'taxonomy_name' );

$args = array(
    'orderby'           => 'name', 
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'        => false, 
    'exclude'           => array(), 
    'exclude_tree'      => array(), 
    'include'           => array(),
    'number'            => '', 
    'fields'            => 'all', 
); 

$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );

var_dump($terms);

restore_current_blog();
```

UPDATE: I've submitted a WP bug to Trac
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35231#ticket

Comment: Every site in a Multisite installation is a *separate site* with its own set of taxonomies. This sounds like the expected behaviour.

Comment: How would this be the expected behavior? There are functions (functions I'm using) that allow a site to access any other site. Get_terms_by is working, but get_terms is not.

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/212918/edit) to add in the code that wasn't working? That might help figure out exactly what was going on.

Comment: Pat, please reread my post. This is the code that is and isn't working. It only works if a taxonomy of the same name exists on the subsite. Which is not the intended functionality since I am switching sites in my code.

Comment: This is expected behaviour, using `switch_to_blog` won't unload the plugins and theme then load in that sites plugins/theme, it just switches the database tables and one or two globals